# QGraphicsPolygonItem not updating QPolygonF co-ordinates when dragged

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom version of QGraphicsPolygonItem which is defined here:

```
#ifndef CUSTOMGPOLYGON_H
#define CUSTOMGPOLYGON_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsPolygonItem>
#include <string>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>

class CustomGPolygon : public QObject, public QGraphicsPolygonItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomGPolygon(QPolygonF poly, QObject *parent);
    ~CustomGPolygon();
    using QGraphicsPolygonItem::boundingRect;
    using QGraphicsPolygonItem::paint;

    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

    QGraphicsTextItem *className;

private slots:
    void deletePolygon();
    void copyPolygon();


signals:
    void duplicatePoly(QPolygonF);

private:
    QMenu menu;

};

#endif // CUSTOMGPOLYGON_H
```

This is the .cpp for my CustomGPolygon:

```
#include "customgpolygon.h"
#include <iostream>
CustomGPolygon::CustomGPolygon(QPolygonF poly, QObject *parent):QGraphicsPolygonItem(poly)
{
    menu.addAction("Copy", this, SLOT(copyPolygon()));
    menu.addAction("Delete", this, SLOT(deletePolygon()));

    connect(this, SIGNAL(duplicatePoly(QPolygonF)), parent, SLOT(drawPolygon(QPolygonF)));
}

CustomGPolygon::~CustomGPolygon()
{}

    void CustomGPolygon::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
        {
        QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);

        QPolygonF poly = this->polygon();
        QPointF edgePoint(0,0);
        for(int i = 0; i<poly.size(); i++){
            if(poly.at(i).x() > edgePoint.x() && poly.at(i).y() > edgePoint.y())
            {
                edgePoint.setX(poly.at(i).x());
                edgePoint.setY(poly.at(i).y());
            }

        }
        this->className->setPos(edgePoint);
        }

}

void CustomGPolygon::deletePolygon()
{

    delete this;
}

void CustomGPolygon::copyPolygon()
{
    QPolygonF poly = this->polygon();
    emit duplicatePoly(poly);
}
```

To Draw one of these polygons onto my QGraphicsScene, I use the following function in my mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::drawPolygon(const QPolygonF &poly)
{
    CustomGPolygon *objectPt = new CustomGPolygon(poly, this);
    objectPt->setPen(pen);
    objectPt->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    scene->addItem(objectPt);
    objectPt->className = textItem;
    map->drawing = false;
}
```

When I drag this drawn polygon I need the co-ordinates of the vectors within the boundingRect to update - which at the moment, they are not doing.

I have tried adding these flags to solve the problem:

```
objectPt->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
objectPt->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
```

However the problem remained

Comment: provide a [mre]. I know the "cause" of the problem but I cannot propose a solution since you do not provide a MRE

Comment: @eyllanesc i added a few more details. let me know if you need any more! Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you show the code that the QPolygonF will use after dragging?

Comment: @eyllanesc have updated it to the full function. Basically it gets the furthest vertex from 0,0 and updates the position of the QGraphicsTextItem that CustomGPoylgon has. However as it stands when I std::cout the x and y for the coords they remain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QPolygonF set in the item is not about the coordinates of the scene but about the coordinates of the item, so moving the item will not change the QPolygonF. It is similar to the position of our face: If roads move with respect to the world but not with respect to ourselves. So if you want to get the polygon with respect to the scene you will have to make a conversion using the mapToScene() method. On the other hand if you want to track the position of the item then you should not use mouseMoveEvent() but itemChange().

On the other hand your calculation of the point is incorrect, what you should compare is the distance based on some metric, for example the Euclidean distance, since for example with your logic if the polygon is in position with negative coordinates then the edgePoint will always be ( 0,0).

Considering the above, the solution is:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class CustomGPolygon: public QObject, public QGraphicsPolygonItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomGPolygon(QPolygonF poly, QObject *parent=nullptr):
        QObject(parent), QGraphicsPolygonItem(poly), className(nullptr){
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
        menu.addAction("Copy", this, &CustomGPolygon::copyPolygon);
        menu.addAction("Delete", this,  &CustomGPolygon::deletePolygon);
        // if(parent)
        // connect(this, &CustomGPolygon:: SIGNAL(duplicatePoly(QPolygonF)), parent, SLOT(drawPolygon(QPolygonF)));
    }
    ~CustomGPolygon(){}
    QGraphicsTextItem *getClassName() const{return className;}
    void setClassName(QGraphicsTextItem *value){className = value;}
protected:
    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value){
        if(change == GraphicsItemChange::ItemPositionChange && !polygon().isEmpty()){
            QPolygonF p = mapToScene(polygon());
            QPointF edgePoint = *std::max_element(p.begin(), p.end(),
                                                  [](const QPointF & x, const QPointF & y) -> bool
            {
                return QVector2D(x).length() > QVector2D(y).length();
            });
            if(className)
                className->setPos(edgePoint);
        }
        return QGraphicsPolygonItem::itemChange(change, value);
    }
private Q_SLOTS:
    void deletePolygon(){delete this;}
    void copyPolygon(){
        QPolygonF poly = mapToScene(polygon());
        Q_EMIT duplicatePoly(poly);
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void duplicatePoly(QPolygonF);
private:
    QGraphicsTextItem *className;
    QMenu menu;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    QPolygonF poly;
    poly << QPointF(0, 0) << QPointF(100, 0) << QPointF(100, 100);
    CustomGPolygon *item = new CustomGPolygon(poly);
    QGraphicsTextItem *textItem = new QGraphicsTextItem("Stack Overflow");
    scene.addItem(textItem);
    scene.addItem(item);
    item->setClassName(textItem);
    view.show();
    view.resize(640, 480);
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Wow man! Thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate it. I have 2 questions for you though as I go through and understand what you've implemented. Firstly, why have you done all the definitions in the header file? I was taught that it was bad practice and only declarations should be in it. Secondly, could you explain this line to me in simpler terms `QPointF edgePoint = *std::max_element(p.begin(), p.end(),[](const QPointF & x, const QPointF & y) -> bool`.

Many thanks once again!

Comment: @wtreston 1) Yes it is a bad practice but my idea is that my answer is compact so I choose the latter. 2) I recommend you read the C++ documentation: [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and lambda methods

Comment: 1. Ok, I will try and adapt it to be header and main file separate. 2. Thank you I will go take a look!